# kubernetes how to write deployment yaml just for replica

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod yaml file(see below). It has all the properties I want, except replica properties. So that I have to write deployment yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-ykt
  labels:
    app: app-ykt
    purpose: ykt_production
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app-ykt
    image: app
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - name: volume-app-ykt
        mountPath: /usr/application
    env:
      - name: spring.config.location
        value: application.properties
  volumes:
      - name: volume-app-ykt
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/docker/datalook-pre-core
          type: Directory
```

When writing deployment file, I have to mention image and other properties which I donot want. What's more, it creates another pod and missing some properties I must have, for example volume. My target is just this replica, so that I could get high availability for the pod. Any solution?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-ykt
  labels:
    app: app-ykt
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-ykt
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-ykt
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-ykt
        image: app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every Kubernetes object has its own requirements. If you want to create `Deployment` you must specify this properties. `Deployment` object is a "abstract" layer for `ReplicaSet` creation and manage it. You cannot create any `Deployment` (RelicaSet) without container properties description (images, volumes etc.)

If you are going to use Kubernetes you need to deploy your apps by "Kubernetes way".  You could create `Deployment` .yml file with your app description, then you would scale the `Deployment` to any count of replicas.

`Service` and maybe `Ingress` objects could help you to load balance among replicas, as @Daein mentioned it above

Your `Deployment` could look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-ykt
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    app: app-ykt
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-ykt
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-ykt
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-ykt
        image: <your_image>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: spring.config.location
          value: application.properties
        volumeMounts:
          - name: volume-app-ykt
            mountPath: /usr/application
      volumes:
      - name: volume-app-ykt
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/docker/datalook-pre-core
          type: Directory
```

This will create `Deployment`, which in turn will automaticly create 3 replicas (3 Pods) with only one `app-ykt` container within

Note: I also think using `hostPath` here is not a good idea, as it mentioned by @Daein, even though I don't know your app configuration. `hostPath` commonly used to access any files on your nodes...

> Remember to use hostPath volumes only if you need to read or write
>   system files on the node. Never use them to persist data across pods.
>   "Kubernetes in Action" (c) Marko Luksa

Comment: just for this case, how to write Deployment yaml file? And if Deployment has all the fields Pod has, then I just need to write service and deployment yaml file. Why we still need pod file?

Comment: `Deployment` will create `Pod`. You don't need `Pod` file at all. I've changed my post

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think hostPath volume is not HA solutions, so you should concern to share a volume as ReadWriteMany Persistent Volume across kubernetes cluster. 
And then you also need the internal load balancer among replicated pods like Services[0].

I hope it help you.

[0][https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/]